# What is the cause of the following error in debugging an Android application in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

[image]

I am attempting to test my code using the emulator, but I am encountering an error that persists even after debugging, preventing me from successfully debugging the program.

Despite uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio and Emulator, the problem still persists and the app doesn't work properly.

Comment: stop the adb and then start it again. That might solve the issue

Comment: How to stop and start adb?

Comment: Open Cmd  and navigate to C:\Users\"Username"\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools. Then run the following commands: adb kill-server , adb start-server

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. I did what you said and even reset the system several times 
@Nishan Khadka