# Android Studio: Unable to see list of emulators, how can I fix this issue?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I seem to have run into a new issue where the option to choose between phone or emulator is disabled. This problem is shown in the photo I provided. It is possible that this new problem is related to the previous problem that I mentioned in the link that is still not solved.

and I can't see the list of emulators.

[text]([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtY4N.png))

previous problem:
[What is the cause of the following error in debugging an Android application in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76303145/what-is-the-cause-of-the-following-error-in-debugging-an-android-application-in?noredirect=1#comment134554385_76303145)

The things I have done:
Removing and installing devices
Change settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to open the task manager and end task of

> **adb file**

then restart the android studio
your devices will show up